# Highlight a list element when I'm browsing the very page

Tags: php, wordpress, uri, highlight

I saw a few tutorial about this problem but none of them satisfied me. I want to highlight the single element of my list which matches the page that I'm browsing. I created the code with php, is a wordpress based website, and the code actually works because when I echo the uri which I'm on it will display the right uri, but the if statement I created to add a class when I'm on the website won't output anything.. and I don't understand why.. anyway.. here's the code:

header.php

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills sliding" id="Jcollapse">
              <li class="<?php if ($current == "/why-chickapea/"){ echo "current";}?>"><a href="/why-chickapea/"><span>Why Chickapea?</span></a></li>
              <li class="<?php if ($current == "/our-pasta/"){ echo "current";}?>"><a href="/our-story/"><span>Our story</span></a></li>
              <li class="<?php if ($current == "/shop-chickapea/"){ echo "current";}?>"><a href="/shop-chickapea/"><span>Shop</span></a></li>
              <li class="<?php if ($current == "/recipes/"){ echo "current";}?>"><a href="/recipes/"><span>Recipes</span></a></li>
              <li class="<?php if ($current == "/blog/"){ echo "current";}?>"><a href="/blog/"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
            </ul>
```

In each page I added a php snippet:

```
<?php $current = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>
```

If I echo the var $current I will obtain the right url in this format: /pagename/

At the end I style the class current with a yellow color

```
.current {
color:yellow;
}
.current a {
color:yellow;
}
```

Does anyone know where my mistake is?

this is the page website: [choosechickapea.com](http://choosechickapea.com)

As you can see the class that my code will generate is empty, but if I echo each value the uri I will obtain is the right one

Comment: If you're using WordPress, the mistake is not using the [navigation menus feature](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus).

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking what you actually have in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`? look at the generated html to see what (if anything) did get generated?

Comment: I'm using my own static menu, which I built without bounding it to the wordpress menu. I did debug, as I wrote in my statement. I echoed the variable and I obtained the right value which is the uri depends on the page I am. For the home page it is something like /index/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest explanation would be, that you print the header before $current is set.

The second simplest explanation is different scopes, meaning either you set $current in a non-global scope or you read it in a non-global scope, and those two (whatever they are) are different. Since someone said wordpress, I guess there is some encapsulation into functions (thus changing the scope). Using the `global` keyword may be *a* solution, but a dirty one. But since you're already avoiding wordpress functions ...

Comment: Yes, actually I had to set the variable inside the header. I declare the variable on each post, for this reason it didn't work. Thank you for you hint!

Comment: this is exactly "different scopes". just saying. But congrats on your correct answer ;o)

Comment: I mean, logically speaking since I declared the variable before the header in the page it should have worked anyway, but for some reason it has to be in the same page (header.php). For a programming prospective it doesn't have much sense, especially in php, because the code is read consequentially, don't you think?

Comment: that is your assumption, that it is. But in fact, it isn't when you let some underlying framework do some work. Unless you explicitly write `include("header.php")` (and that actually does what you think it does) you're slave to the framework, wordpress in that example.
most frameworks that allow plugins/extensions will wrap usercode into a function, so that you can avoid any unwanted side effects (for example a $current variable bleeding into the header code which could very well be unwanted)

Answer (score 0):

The actual code is:

Before declaring in the header the if statement, SET the value of the variable. If you'll declare in the body, even before loading the header with a, for example require once or in wordpress:

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>
```

It won't work, the variable has to be set in the header like this:

```
<?php $current = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>
    <header class="navbar-fixed-top">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills sliding">
              <li class="<?php if ($current == "/your-url/"){ echo "current";}?>"><a href="/your-url/"><span>your url</span></a></li>
              <li class="<?php if ($current == "/other-url/"){ echo "current";}?>"><a href="/other-url/"><span>/other url/</span></a></li>
              </ul>
</header>
```